# How does location dependent website loading work?

Tags: dns, http, redirection

When I type in `udacity.com` in my web browser, it automatically loads `https://in.udacity.com`

How does this work?

Does the *udacity.com* machine redirect all requests coming from IPs belonging to India to *in.udacity.com* using `HTTP REDIRECT 301`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Udacity uses Cloudflare as a proxy to their actual servers. Any request to `https://www.udacity.com` will first go to Cloudflare and will then be redirected to the appropriate domain for the geolocation of the origin.

Check the response of:

```
curl -iv https://www.udacity.com
```

It's therefore the IP address from which your location can be identified. Cloudflare [offers this service](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-) — it will add a geolocation header to any request, which the Udacity servers then use to determine which domain to redirect you to.

This method of determining the location is not always precise and may result in false positives, particularly if you are using a VPN provider. Also, it's rather slow depending on how you look up the geolocation. A provider like Cloudflare can do it relatively fast, as they process lots of requests and can cache the information, so it does not add up to the request time. For your small-business website, I would not recommend using the IP to determine the user's location.

The redirect is not permanent, by the way, as you might change countries. So it does not make sense to *always* redirect you to a specific subdomain. Instead it uses a [`302 Found` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), which is temporary.

Another method of redirecting the user based on their location would be to check the [`Accept-Language` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) of the browser, which specifies the client locale. The locale may be, for example, `fr-CH`, which says that you're preferring French, with  a Swiss locale (they speak French in Switzerland, but it's subtly different from the French they speak in France, hence the need to differentiate). This, however, is also not always reliable — I have all my software set to American English, and this regularly makes websites think I'm based in America. Here, a geolocation-based approach would be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTTP header called "Accept-Language" in the request your browser sends to the server which tells what language you prefer and that information can be used on the server to redirect you to the appropriate site regardless your IP address.

Determining your location based on your IP address (usig GeoLocation databases) could be an another solution, however those databases are usually not 100% accurate.

Comment: In either case, is the redirection to different URL due to HTTP REDIRECT 301?

Comment: @karthikts No, use `curl -iv https://www.udacity.com` to see the actual response — it's a 302 response.

Comment: Udacity is not using the `Accept-Language` parameter. You can try that for yourself by setting a different one—it's using the IP address instead.